# Python find value from nested list parent element

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration, parent-child, nested-lists

I saved a Parent - Child structure inside a nested list with Python.

```
PC_List = [[1,1,2],[1,2,8],[1,3,5],[2,4,7],[3,5,1]]
```

First index of sub list element is ParentID,
Second index of sub list element is ChildID,
Third index of sub list element is Value

What is the best and fastest way to append the Value from sub list element where childID = current ParentID ?
New List should look like this

```
New_PC_List = [[1,1,2],[1,2,8,2],[1,3,5,2],[2,4,7,8],[3,5,1,5]]
```

I would appreciate some tipps.
P.S. len of PC_List can go over 1Million rows.

Thank you

Comment: The logic you're trying to describe is pretty difficult to follow. You might need to reword things to get some meaningful help here.

Comment: That's not valid syntax, what's the first value in the first nested list? Is it another int? 1?

Comment: Hi, your list is not defined correctly (will give syntax error), was the minus sign meant to be another character?

Comment: Your output doesn't fit your description of the problem. In none of the nested lists the first and the second value are equal.

Comment: Ok.... I think I got the logic of your puzzle. So, how would you solve `[ [1,2,3], [1,2,4], [5,6,7] ]`?

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly PC_List[ 1 ][ 0 ] and PC_List[ 1 ][ 0 ] are equal to PC_List[ 0 ][ 1 ] in my example. That is why they append value from PC_List[ 0 ][ 1 ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first construct a dict that maps "id" to the "value", and then use it to append the values.

```py
PC_List = [[1,1,2],[1,2,8],[1,3,5],[2,4,7],[3,5,1]]
values = {k: v for _, k, v in PC_List}

output = [[p, c, v, values[p]] for p, c, v in PC_List]
print(output)
# [[1, 1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 8, 2], [1, 3, 5, 2], [2, 4, 7, 8], [3, 5, 1, 5]]
```

Comment: Hello j1-lee, thanks that worked. Can you give me some insights what happens here ?

Comment: @Williamx just recently I found out that making edits adding explanation to code-only answers (from other people) is frowned upon, so I'll add the explanation as an comment: first, `values` is an [dictionary comprehension](https://peps.python.org/pep-0274/), mapping the "self `Value`" to it's respective "self `ID`". Then, using `values` dict, he used a [list comprehension](https://peps.python.org/pep-0202/) to generate a list, where every element of the list is a list itself and the inner list has the three original elements plus the parent value (accessed from the dict passing the `parentID`)

Answer (score 0):

It was kind of hard to follow what you wanted, but after giving the first element of the list a parent id of 0 (you're using 1-indexing so I assume that's alright), I think this does what you want:

```
PC_List = [[0,1,2],[1,2,8],[1,3,5],[2,4,7],[3,5,1]]
for i in range(1,len(PC_List)):
    PC_List[i].append(PC_List[PC_List[i][0]-1][2])
```

This solution changes the original list, but this can be fixed with copy.deepcopy if you prefer.

Comment: Hello Leander, your answer worked for this example but I need a way where I find parentID with different distances

Comment: Hi WIlliam, your question is too vague for me, hope you figure out your problem. It seem's j1-lee gets it!